# How Can I Install Cordova Plugins Using Visual Studio Cordova?

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2013, cordova-plugins, opentok

I installed Cordova using the latest version of Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova. I'm trying to follow the instructions to install the opentok plugin here: https://github.com/songz/cordova-plugin-opentok but I'm having trouble figuring out how to install this plugin to my project. I'm not sure what CLI they're talking about. I'm assuming this tutorial is for non-VS (Though I'm not sure if it still applies to my setup.) I just installed the latest VS Tools for Cordova and am running Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate.

Thank you all.

Edit: I've found the answer and posted the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the answer. Within Visual Studio you can access the Cordova for VS documentation and in it there's a section for plugins. Plugins can be installed from within Visual Studio as described here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn757051.aspx

[image: Add Plugins For Cordova in Visual Studio]

This has also been found thanks to [sanfor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1744702/sanfor):

After building for a native (non-Ripple) target for any platform, the contents of the bld/Debug (or bld/Release if you did a release build) folder is a standard Cordova Command Line Interface (CLI) project. -[Visual Studio Cordova FAQ](http://www.visualstudio.com/explore/cordova-faq-vs). So you should be able to run it after once building for some platform.

This could be used as an alternate method to the GUI.

Answer (score 1):

It's no shame not to understand all this Cordova scene, took me a lot time also to get used to it.. The *CLI* refers Command-Line Interface which means technically what you can do on Command prompt (*cmd.exe*). You can see the Cordova's own CLI tutorial on their [own site](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html).

Now, about installing the plugin. The plugin is **not** available for Windows Phones, only for Android and iOS. If you are targeting only these platforms, you can install it like this

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/songz/cordova-plugin-opentok/
```

from command-line within your projects root folder (the one that has the *www* folder in it). You can usually find the instructions for installation from within the GitHub project. In this case that reads there too.

If you would absolutely need it for Windows Phone, please post another question about how to get it for Windows and I can give you tutorial for how to create plugins for features that doesn't yet exist, in case such a plugin doesn't yet exist. If such plugin doesn't yet exist, it will require some knowledge of C# and Windows Phone coding.

Hope this clarified it a little and feel free to poke me on Stack Overflow chat if necessary.

Comment: It's not for Windows Phone. I'm mainly targeting IOS and Android. My confusion comes from the fact that I installed Cordova via the VS Tools package. I know very well what CLI is but what's uncertain is that since I installed the VS version should I be using the Windows CMD/Powershell or is there a CLI interface in VS I can use to install the plugin. I noticed that in the nuget package manager there's a package for "OpenTok API" I can add to my project but I'm guessing that wont play well with droid/ios. Since I installed Cordova via the VS package IDK where cordova is to run the command.

Comment: Oh, I am sorry for misinterpreting your question then. Anyway, you can look for file called _cordova_ on your computer in case the VS would've installed for you and then add that to your path to be able to use Cordova the normal way. After all, it makes it much clearer to use plain Cordova CLI than try to do it with the VS.

Comment: Here is what I installed which includes Cordova, the emulators, etc. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42675 . I'm currently searching my drive for "cordova" but nothing has been returned so far.

Comment: _After building for a native (non-Ripple) target for any platform, the contents of the bld/Debug (or bld/Release if you did a release build) folder is a standard Cordova Command Line Interface (CLI) project._ -[Visual Studio Cordova FAQ](http://www.visualstudio.com/explore/cordova-faq-vs). So you should be able to run it after once building for some platform.

Comment: Thank you for that, I'll add it to the solution I posted. I could use an upvote (I can't) since I found the correct way to do it. What you just commented is useful too I'm guessing as an alternate method so I'll add that to the solution. Thanks.

Comment: I've added the extra info from your last comment and credited you for it.

Comment: Actually an upvote for the question and answer would be appropriate. This question and answer is nowhere on stackexchange.